# Prove $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ is uniformly continuous at $N(0;r)^c$ for any $r >0$

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

I tried $\left \vert \frac{\sin x}{x^2} -  \frac{\sin c}{c^2}\right \vert \leq \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{c^2} < \epsilon$, but it doesn't help me much with $\vert x - c \vert < \delta$. How can I prove this?

Comment: Hint: show that the derivative is uniformly bounded for $|x|\geq r>0$.

Comment: Can you give me more details? I already tried that strategy, but it gives a bound related to r, not \delta.

Comment: The bound will naturally depend on $r$ but that is not a problem since $r$ is fixed. Since the function blows up at $x=0$, you can expect the bound to become worse as $r\to 0$, so it has to depend on $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $x,y \neq 0$,

$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \frac{\sin y}{y^2} \right| = \left|\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \frac{\sin x}{xy} + \frac{\sin x}{xy}- \frac{\sin y}{y^2}\right| \\\leqslant \left|\frac{\sin x }{x}\right|\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right| + \frac{1}{|y|}\left| \frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{\sin y}{y}\right|\\ = \left|\frac{\sin x }{x}\right|\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right| + \frac{1}{|y|}\left| \frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{\sin x }{y} + \frac{\sin x}{y}-\frac{\sin y}{y}\right|\\ \leqslant \left|\frac{\sin x }{x}\right|\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right| + \frac{|\sin x|}{|y|}\left| \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1 }{y}\right|  + \frac{1}{|y|^2}\left|\sin x-\sin y\right|$$

Since $\left| \frac{\sin x}{x}\right|= \frac{|\sin x|}{|x|} \leqslant 1$ and $|\sin x | \leqslant 1$, it follows that

$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \frac{\sin y}{y^2} \right| \leqslant \left(1 + \frac{1}{|y|} \right)\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right| +  \frac{1}{|y|^2}\left|\sin x-\sin y\right| \\ =\left(1 + \frac{1}{|y|} \right)\frac{|x-y|}{|x||y|} +  \frac{1}{|y|^2}\left|\sin x-\sin y\right|,$$

and for  all $x,y \in [r,\infty)\cup (-\infty,-r],$

$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \frac{\sin y}{y^2} \right| \leqslant \frac{1+r}{r^3}|x-y| + \frac{1}{r^2}|\sin x - \sin y|$$

Using the [prosthaphaeresis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis) , we get $|\sin x - \sin y | \leqslant |x - y|$ and it follows that

$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \frac{\sin y}{y^2} \right| \leqslant \frac{1+r}{r^3}|x-y| + \frac{1}{r^2}| x -  y| = \frac{1+2r}{r^3}|x-y|,$$

directly proving uniform continuity on $[r,\infty)\cup (-\infty,-r]$ where $r > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$|f'(x) |=| \frac{cos(x)}{x^2} + \frac{-2sin(x)}{x^3}|\leqslant M+C $ , the derivative is bounded from a starting point of x$_\beta$  . try to continue .
I think the function isn't uniformly continues because the limit as x goes to 0 doesn't  exist .

Comment: But my book suggests NOT to use derivation or related concepts. Can I prove it directly?

Comment: The problem is phrased a bit ambigously. I assume $c$ means complement, i.e., you need to prove uniform convergence outside $(0,r)$ with some fixed $r>0$. For this to work, one has to assume $x>0$ too.